# Cisco Console Cable DIY

Tags: cisco, cable, access-point

I received today a cisco cap3702i-e-k9 access point, but sadly i dont have any console cable that i can use.
Only things i have for now is PL2303, maybe i can combine it with something.

Hello.
I received today a cisco access point cap3702i-e-k9. I want to configure it to autonomous but sadly i dont have any console cable with me.
So, is it possible to do my own cable? I have a PL2303 and a lot of lot usb cables and ethernet 5e. I tried using different schemes but only thing i achieved was getting weird characters in putty.

Thank you.

Comment: It is a rolled cable.

Comment: @RonMaupin what do you mean? I just need to connect ap to my pc using usb

Comment: Have you googled "cisco console serial pinout"? It's a pretty well known "standard" - been around for 40+ years.

Comment: Then you need a USB to serial converter to which you connect a Cisco console (rolled) cable.

Comment: @Ricky Of course, that's what I did first. Just connecting using this gave me "weird" characters in the putty console. But the fact is, can I make such a cable using these things?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you have Putty set to 8N1?

Comment: If you have cable, connectors, and a crimper, then make a rolled cable. You still need a USB to serial converter to which to connect it.

Comment: @RonMaupin Yes. I set it to 8n1. Isn’t PL2303 USB to serial converter?

Comment: Im pretty sure its possible, but when im connecting RX-TX, TX-RX im not getting anything in console, but if i try RX-RX, TX-TX im getting something, but only weird characters.

Comment: It is just a rolled cable. Connect 1 to 8, 2 to 7, 3 to 6, and 4 to 5. Basically, on a flat cable, you just roll one end over. If you have that, and you get nothing or strange characters, then you have the wrong serial settings in your terminal application.

Comment: "_Isn’t PL2303 USB to serial converter?_" I have no idea.